# What is the format of the file serving as the operand to the --systemProperties command line argument?

Tags: payara-micro

When running Payara Micro, you can [use the `--systemProperties` command line argument to specify a file containing system properties to set](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/documentation/payara-micro/configuring/config-sys-props.html).  What is the format of this file?

As an example (using Payara Micro 172), if I create a file called `system.properties` and use it via:

```
java -jar myPayaraJar.jar ... --systemProperties system.properties
```

...and it looks like this:

```
payaramicro.disablePhoneHome=true
```

...then I do not see that phoning home has been disabled.  By contrast, if I specify `--disablephonehome` as the command line option, I do see that Payara has disabled this feature.

Is there a different format for this properties file that I should be using instead?

Comment: Have you tried setting the system properties in all lower case? A while back the command line options were case sensitive and they were changed so case doesn't matter. It could be that this bit of code doesn't scrub out cases since I think it's older than the change to ignore case in the command line options. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the file is usual Java properties file.

However, there seems to be a bug in Payara Micro. I see you've already raised a bug in github which is the best you could do: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1953

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer! Yes, that's correct: while it seems possible to directly pass system properties that will override certain command line options, it does not seem to be possible to do so by way of the `--systemPropertiesFile` argument at the moment.  That's fine; at least I understand how it's _supposed_ to work!

Answer (score 0):

I see from the [source code](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/payara-blue-4.1.2.172/appserver/extras/payara-micro/payara-micro-core/src/main/java/fish/payara/micro/impl/PayaraMicroImpl.java#L1290) that the format of this file is a regular `java.util.Properties` file.  There must be some other bug going on.